# MagicalRecord saveWithBlock crash

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord

I try to run this code on the device with iOS 7 (actually it's worked well on the simulator)
I used MR 2.2 and generated Core Data classes with mogenerator

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

            NewsEntity *newsEntity = [NewsEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];
        newsEntity.newsId = jsonObject[@"News_Id"];

    }
    completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
        if (!success || nil != error)
        {
          NSLog(@"MagicalRecord saveWithBlock error: %@", error.description);
        }
        else
        {
            [self updateUI];
        }
    }];
```

And I had an exception on this line of code

```
NewsEntity *newsEntity = [NewsEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];
```

bt seems like that

```
* thread #5: tid = 0x31b342, 0x3aaafcc0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'NSManagedObjectContext Queue', stop reason = breakpoint 3.3
  * frame #0: 0x3aaafcc0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x2fd50030 CoreData`+[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 204
    frame #2: 0x00053f02 TestApp`+[_NewsEntity insertInManagedObjectContext:](self=0x00be4480, _cmd=0x369db6dc, moc_=0x16789640) + 322 at _NewsEntity.m:28
    frame #3: 0x0014de3e TestApp`+[NSManagedObject(self=0x00be4480, _cmd=0x00975bb0, context=0x16789640) MR_createInContext:] + 138 at NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m:157
    frame #4: 0x00057df4 TestApp`__52-[NewsViewController saveDataToPersistentStorage:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>, localContext=0x16789640) + 472 at NewsViewController.m:115
    frame #5: 0x00144282 TestApp`__51+[MagicalRecord(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) saveWithBlock:completion:]_block_invoke + 46 at MagicalRecord+Actions.m:28
    frame #6: 0x2fdaca70
```

Also I had a termination exception like this

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'NewsEntity' in this model.'
```

I only added [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack]; to the AppDelegate

Could you have any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to add Core Data model to Target Membership